# Javascript array how do i do a function for each line in array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

okay so here's my current script

```
<html>
<head>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function textareaToArray(t){
        return t.value.split(/[\n\r]+/);
        }
        function showArray(msg){
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = msg.join("&#013;");
        }
    </script>


    </head>
        <title>
        Welcome To ....
        </title>
<body>
        <center>
        <h1> WELCOME TO .... </h1></center>

    </br>
    </br>
    </br>

<center>

        <form>
        <textarea rows="10" cols="60" name="alpha"></textarea>
        <br>
        <input type="button"
        value="show array"
        onclick="showArray(textareaToArray(this.form.alpha ))">
        </form>
</center>
    </br>
<center>
        <textarea id="message" rows="6" cols="60" name="message"></textarea>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

as you can see the javascript function basically just outputs the array into the second text area.

how can I invoke a function for each line in the array

e.g.

a function to use line in array post to php script as post  data then echo the result back after this it does the same for the next line can any one help me on how I would post each line to a php script and echo the response back into the text area

Comment: Please, use indentation. Nobody's going read that.

Comment: Just to fix your semantics, there are no "lines" in an array, an array is object that contains elements, what you should be asking is "how do I iterate through an array".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I redid your entire example, also fixed some other small errors in your html.

```
<html><head><title>Welcome To ....</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function textareaToArray(t){
            return t.value.split(/[\n\r]+/);
        }
        function showArray(msg){
            for(i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
                // something per item
                alert(msg[i]);
            }
            // the old code
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = msg.join("&#013;");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> WELCOME TO .... </h1>
    <form>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="60" name="alpha"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="show array" onclick="showArray(textareaToArray(this.form.alpha ))">
    </form>
    <br>
    <textarea id="message" rows="6" cols="60" name="message"></textarea>
</body></html>
```

Where the "alert" happens is where you could add code for each item in the array.  Now for the warning, there is no input checking.. this code is brutally insecure and if you are allowing to pass things from a textarea, this is definitely a vector for XSS attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer is:

`for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    alert(array[i])`

Comment: Don't use a `for...in` loop to iterate over an array.